# Proof that Compact Sets of $R^n$ are measurable

Tags: real-analysis

This is from the Stein Shakarchi text, pg 17 - proof that closed sets are measurable.

The proof begins by proving that all compact sets $F$ of $R^n$ are measurable. To confirm, does the only reason why compactness of $F$ is important lie in choosing an open cover with finite measure?

Why does the proof break when I simply assume that $F$ is closed? (Unbounded)

http://press.princeton.edu/chapters/s8008.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authors make the convenient assumption $F$ compact in order to guarantee that both $F$ and an open cover have finite outer measure.

To see what would go wrong otherwise, take $F = (-\infty,0]\cup [1,\infty)$.  then $O = \mathbb{R}$ satisfies vacuously $m_*(O)\leq m_*(F)+\epsilon $ but the proof will break down at the beginning of page 18; the union of the little cubes will not have small measure.

It will be instructive to through the argument yourself with these choices and see how precisely it breaks down.

Answer (score 4):

The proof doesn't really need that $F$ is a compact set. The proof also holds if $F$ is a closed set with finite outer Lebesgue measure. Such sets can be unbounded, see for example
$$\bigcup \limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} [i - 2^{-i}, i + 2^{-i}].$$